# Unable to install erlang 19 from epel. RHEL

Tags: erlang

I am trying to install RabbitMQ which needs Erlang above 16. However when I try to install Erlang it installs 14B03 from epel repository.

When I manually download the RPM file and try to install it, it fails due to dependencies. Please suggest.

I am having RHEL 6.8 & Epel 6.8

Comment: You could try using `kerl` which builds from source.

Answer (score 1):

You can purge erlang completely and install rpm version you need.
If you don't want purge old version, check [installing multiple versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894447/installing-more-than-one-version-of-erlang-otp-on-a-machine)